# Saving data as a PHP script / as a .php file? (Purely theoretical)

Tags: php, database, security

I know this would be all kinds of bad form, but am curious as to whether or not this would work.

Let's say I'm a total hopeless case who doesn't know a thing about SQL, so normally I go saving all my data as .txt files (which, sadly, was true of me until not-so-long-ago).

I know that if someone were to stumble upon the URL of one of these .txt files, they'd (obviously) be able to see all the data inside it. So I think, "What if I saved the data inside a PHP script/file? That way if anyone stumbles across it they'll just see a blank page because the server will execute it as PHP."

So here's the ultra-confidential array of data I want to save:

```
$myArray = array("apple","orange","banana");
```

I take this array and do this:

```
file_put_contents("data.php", "<?php \$var=\"" . htmlentities(json_encode($myArray)) . "\"; ?>");
```

The result is a file called "data.php" that contains one line of code:

```
<?php $var="[&quot;apple&quot;,&quot;orange&quot;,&quot;banana&quot;]"; ?>
```

This file is invisible to any outside users; it's valid PHP code and the server executes it as such, but all it does is declare a variable.

However, I can access the data recorded in data.php from another file by doing this:

```
$importVar = htmlentities(file_get_contents("data.php"));
$importVarBeg = 20;
$importVarEnd = 13;
$importVar = html_entity_decode(substr($importVar, $importVarBeg, strlen($importVar) - ($importVarBeg + $importVarEnd)));
$importVarArray = json_decode(html_entity_decode($importVar));
```

Now `$importVarArray` contains my original super-confidential data array, to do with as I please!

So again, I know this is a really stupid way to do things, but stupidity aside, is it actually a viable way of storing data such that it's totally inaccessible to outside users?

EDIT: Clarifying "outside user" -- anyone hitting my website. Let's say I'm the only person using my server.

Comment: "I know that it's really stupid, but is it a viable solution?" <- these two terms seem to contradict each other. It can be either stupid or viable, but not both.

Comment: what do you mean, "outside users"? People hitting your website? You shouldn't be storing critical data like that inside the document root anyways. Other users on a shared server? Unless the provider's on the ball and knows what they're doing, your stuff's fully open to every other user on the server.

Comment: `<php /*useless_post*/ ?>` ... totally invisible for outsiders ;)

Comment: I remember doing something similar with [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) when I had just started learning PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going through this circus, why not have your web server deny requests to a particular directory, dump your raw data in that directory? Your scripts will still be able to read from there; just that all external requests will be denied.

Or, even simpler - simply store the content outside of your web root.

Comment: Better yet, store the flat files in a path that is not web accessible at all.

Comment: I get that. This isn't something I'm actually doing; I'm just wondering whether it would actually be water-tight to people who don't have access to my server.

Comment: No. Its not. Anytime you have a callable from outside (in your case, a PHP script), have access to parts of the file system that aren't meant to be public (like a directory outside the document root), you have a security vulnerability.  Not to mention your data is just sitting there for any and all to see, modify, delete, etc.

Comment: I thought I'd add: this answer is also good advice to follow for people who use SQLite as it faces the same security concerns as straight text files.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is out of reach of general Internet users, but still visible to anyone who has access to the server.

So if the data is confidential you should encrypt it!